# "Circular Indent"?

Tags: modeling, objects, bezier-curves

I'm kinda new to Blender, so still starting out...

How do you make this? (if Possible Step-by-Step)

[image: Screenshot from Logitech website]

Can't quite find on the internet the exact way to do this...

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a cube, scale it on Z in Edit mode, select the edge ring (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> left click) (or create a plane, bevel the corners and extrude the whole plane):

[image]

Bevel with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>:

[image]

Select the top edge with loop select and press <kbd>i</kbd> to inset:

[image]

Activate the *LoopTools* addon and right click > *LoopTools > Circle*, rotate the circle on Z to correctly align with the topology:

[image]

Inset again, lower down the inset:

[image]

Add some edge loops with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> in order to sharpen the edges while you'll have a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Give your object a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, right click on it to *Shade Smooth*:

[image]

Comment: the godfather of modelling did it again....+1

Comment: this one is easy   ^^

Comment: read my answer...and you know...not for everybody.... :D

Comment: I could read it  ^^ ...

Comment: maybe you should first read point 13...it is the most important one which makes my answer great and makes my result look as good as yours :D

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one question: At this step: "Select the top edge with loop select and press i to inset" the lines coming from the bevel are overlapping each other, why is that?

Comment: it's the effect of the scale, before it happens you can scale with S instead, as much as needed, then LoopTools > Circle

Comment: _"select the edge ring (Alt Shift right click)"_ — did you mean left click? With Alt+Shift held down the RMB appears to do nothing, while the statusbar shows "Loop Select" for the LMB.

Comment: Sorry I probably meant Ctrl+Alt+RMB, is it right?

Comment: Ah! Yeah, Ctrl + Alt is Edge Ring Select — still the LMB, not the RMB, though.

Comment: ok thanks I've corrected, my shortcuts are customed, that's why

Answer (score 5):

And just to show you how you shouldn't do it...you can follow this (because it uses too much vertices and the result looks so much shittier than moonboots does)....

1. Shift A -> Mesh -> Plane

[image]

2. Tab -> edit mode

[image]

3. right click -> subdivide

[image]

4. in the bottom left corner press the >

[image]

5. enter 40

[image]

6. repeat step 3 to 5, but with value 3

[image]

7. click outside to deselect

[image]

8. select one vertex in the middle

[image]

9. check proportional editing

[image]

10. choose inverse square

[image]

11. press G -> Z and move your cursor slowly down until your are satisfied, scroll your mousewheel up and down until you are satisfied

[image]

12. press tab to go to object mode

[image]

13. delete that shit and follow moonboots great answer

Comment: whoever upvoted this answer....thank you! you have humor!!!! :D

Comment: I did but I wonder how you were able to find the exact center vertex

Comment: Haha thanks anyways!

Comment: @Chris, did you have to write a kind of python script or something

Comment: Fantastic! Now I need to retopologize all of my assets this way!

Comment: i am thinking about making a geometry nodes solution for this... :D

Comment: love the pixel-art look of the result :D